# CartThrob - Clear *Customer* Info

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, sessions, shopping-cart

If a customer adds products to the basket, fills in their details and then processes a payment and it errors / fails / cancels and they press back (Or click the go back link) in their browser to go back and amend their address (Or the bit that is incorrect) then submit the details again. It doesn't seem to remove the previous address from the session.

Is there a way of just clearing the *customer_info* part of the CartThrob session, not the full basket?

I know of this tag:

```
{exp:cartthrob:clear_cart clear_customer_info="yes"}
```

But I don't want to clear the cart, just the *customer_info*

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.. not sure how best to fix at the moment...

Comment: @JohnHunt Sadly I never found a solution. But I'm hoping recent CT updates fixed this. Maybe check the changelog